# Memory leaks in pthread even if the state is detached

Tags: linux, multithreading, memory-leaks, pthreads, valgrind

I am learning pthreads programming.

I understood that there are two states of thread:
1. Joinable
2. Detachable

In case of Joinable, we need to call pthread_join to free the resources(stack), whereas in case of detached there is no need to call pthread_join and the resources will be freed on thread exit.

I wrote a sample program to observe the behavior

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *threadFn(void *arg)
{

 pthread_detach(pthread_self());
 sleep(1);
 printf("Thread Fn\n");
 pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

 pthread_t tid;
 int ret = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, threadFn, NULL);

 if (ret != 0) {
  perror("Thread Creation Error\n");
  exit(1);
 }
 printf("After thread created in Main\n");
 pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

When i try to check any mem leaks with valgrind it gave me leaks of 272 bytes. Can you show me why is the leak happening here.

```
$valgrind --leak-check=full ./app
==38649== 
==38649== HEAP SUMMARY:
==38649==     in use at exit: 272 bytes in 1 blocks
==38649==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 6 frees, 2,990 bytes allocated
==38649== 
==38649== 272 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 1
==38649==    at 0x4C31B25: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==38649==    by 0x40134A6: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:286)
==38649==    by 0x40134A6: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:530)
==38649==    by 0x4E44227: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:627)
==38649==    by 0x4E44227: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:644)
==38649==    by 0x108902: main (2.c:18)
==38649== 
==38649== LEAK SUMMARY:
==38649==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==38649==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==38649==      possibly lost: 272 bytes in 1 blocks
==38649==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==38649==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==38649== 
==38649== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==38649== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expectation is correct that there shouldn't be any leaks in main thread once you call `pthread_exit`.

However, what you observe is a quirk of the implementation you're using (which is likely to be glibc) - pthreads library (glibc implementation) re-uses the initially allocated stack for threads - like a cache so that previously allocated stacks can be re-used whenever possible.

Valgrind simply reports what it "sees" (something was allocated but not de-allocated). But it's not a real leak, so you don't need to worry about this.

If you "reverse" the logic (main thread exits as the last thread) then you wouldn't see leaks because the initially allocated stack space is properly free'd by the main thread. But this leak isn't a real leak in any case and you can safely ignore this.

You can also setup a [*suppression file*](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress) so that Valgrind doesn't complain about this (which is to inform Valgrind that "I know this isn't not real leak, so don't report this"), such as:

```
{
   Pthread_Stack_Leaks_Ignore
   Memcheck:Leak
   fun:calloc
   fun:allocate_dtv
   fun:_dl_allocate_tls
   fun:allocate_stack
   fun:pthread_create*

}
```